# Moving a sine wave in Tkinter

Tags: python, python-2.7, animation, tkinter, trigonometry

I need to know **how to see on the screen a sine wave moving using Tkinter**
I already did that with pygame but It is complicated that I thought do it with Tkinter.
I think that the first that I need to do is define a function that draw the sine waves and then define other function that give movement to this draws. Is that correct? or Am I thinking wrong? How can move a sine wave on the screen?

The code that I extract of matplotlib.org was:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x = np.arange(0, 2*np.pi, 0.01)        # x-array
line, = ax.plot(x, np.sin(x))

def animate(i):
    line.set_ydata(np.sin(x+i/10.0))  # update the data
    return line,

#Init only required for blitting to give a clean slate.
def init():
    line.set_ydata(np.ma.array(x, mask=True))
    return line,

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, np.arange(1, 200), init_func=init, interval=25, blit=True)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand 'moving' but matplotlib could most likely be used.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(frameon=False)
ax = fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1])
ax.axis('off')

ax.plot(range(10))
plt.show()
```

Comment: I already do with matplotlib now I want to use Tkinter for ANIMATE a sine wave

Comment: I don't get it. But you could generate a list of pictures, and the show them in succession in Tkinter. But whats wrong with the matplotlib solution?

Comment: Because I need to draw more than one sine wave (seven). I cannot have any axis or button also I have to change the size of the window to full screen. I have to visualize only the sine wave and nothing more.

Comment: Matplotlib is the way to go.  It can do all you mentioned.

Comment: Can you give me the code for that I try to remove the axis and failed why is the reason that I am trying with Tkinter

Comment: I try to use the code that you give me in the code that I just put above but then show me this Errors: TypeError: 'Figure' object is not iterable in line 8 or AttributeError: 'Line2D' object has no attribute 'axis' in line 12

Comment: I do not know where you paste my code. If you paste the above in an empty .py file and run it, it will work.

Comment: Yes, It works now I can see a line without the axis, thank you for that. Now, ¿How to combine both codes? because what I need to see is a n animation of a sine wave

Answer (score 0):

I finally move seven sine waves with the help of a lot of other posts. this is the final result:

```
import pygame
import time
import math
import random

canvas_width=1308
canvas_height=720
canvas_s=1004

rojo=pygame.Color(255,0,0)
verde=pygame.Color(0,255,0)
azul=pygame.Color(0,0,255)
amarillo=pygame.Color(255,255,0,0)
marron=pygame.Color(85,65,0)
morado=pygame.Color(255,0,255)
naranja=pygame.Color(255,128,0)
lin=pygame.Color(255,255,255)
background_color=pygame.Color(0,0,0)

pygame.init()
# initialization of font module and creating a font to draw with
pygame.font.init()
fontdir=pygame.font.match_font('TimesNewRoman',False,False)
myfont = pygame.font.Font(fontdir,60)
pygame.display.set_caption("Monitor Signos Vitales")

screen=pygame.display.set_mode((canvas_width,canvas_height))
screen.fill(background_color)

surface=pygame.Surface((canvas_width,canvas_s))
surface.fill(background_color)

# creating the random list and their corresponding surfaces
random_list=[random.randrange(0,1000) for x in range(5)]
text_list=[myfont.render(str(x),True,lin) for x in random_list]

running=True
while running:
    pos=(1220,0)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            running=False

    surface.fill(background_color)

    for text in text_list:
        surface.blit(text,pos)
        pos=(pos[0],pos[1]+180)

    pygame.draw.line(surface, lin, (0, 90), (1004, 90))
    pygame.draw.line(surface, lin, (0, 180), (1004, 180))
    pygame.draw.line(surface, lin, (0, 270), (1004, 270))
    pygame.draw.line(surface, lin, (0, 360), (1004, 360))
    pygame.draw.line(surface, lin, (0, 450), (1004, 450))
    pygame.draw.line(surface, lin, (0, 540), (1004, 540))
    pygame.draw.line(surface, lin, (0, 630), (1004, 630))
    pygame.draw.line(surface, lin, (1004, 0), (1004, 720))
    pygame.draw.line(surface, lin, (1004, 180), (1308, 180))
    pygame.draw.line(surface, lin, (1004, 360), (1308, 360))
    pygame.draw.line(surface, lin, (1004, 540), (1308, 540))

    frecuency=2;frecuency0=4;frecuency1=8;frecuency2=16;frecuency3=5;frecuency4=10;frecuency5=15
    amplitude=30
    speed=2
    for x0 in range(0,canvas_s):
        y0=int((canvas_height/2)+amplitude*math.sin(frecuency*((float(x0)/canvas_s)*(2*math.pi)+(speed*time.time()))+270)-270)
        surface.set_at((x0,y0),amarillo)
    for x1 in range(0,canvas_s):
        y1=int((canvas_height/2)+amplitude*math.sin(frecuency0*((float(x1)/canvas_s)*(2*math.pi)+(speed*time.time()))+180)-180)
        surface.set_at((x1,y1),verde)
    for x2 in range(0,canvas_s):
        y2=int((canvas_height/2)+amplitude*math.sin(frecuency1*((float(x2)/canvas_s)*(2*math.pi)+(speed*time.time()))+90)-90)
        surface.set_at((x2,y2),naranja)
    for x3 in range(0,canvas_s):
        y3=int((canvas_height/2)+amplitude*math.sin(frecuency2*((float(x3)/canvas_s)*(2*math.pi)+(speed*time.time()))))
        surface.set_at((x3,y3),azul)
    for x4 in range(0,canvas_s):
        y4=int((canvas_height/2)+amplitude*math.sin(frecuency3*((float(x4)/canvas_s)*(2*math.pi)+(speed*time.time()))-90)+90)
        surface.set_at((x4,y4),rojo)
    for x5 in range(0,canvas_s):
        y5=int((canvas_height/2)+amplitude*math.sin(frecuency4*((float(x5)/canvas_s)*(2*math.pi)+(speed*time.time()))-180)+180)
        surface.set_at((x5,y5),marron)
    for x6 in range(0,canvas_s):
        y6=int((canvas_height/2)+amplitude*math.sin(frecuency5*((float(x6)/canvas_s)*(2*math.pi)+(speed*time.time()))-270)+270)
        surface.set_at((x6,y6),morado)

    screen.blit(surface,(0,0))
    pygame.display.flip()
```

P.D: Please vote